# Подключаем реакт. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подключаю так:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Проверяю консолью, если ли объект ReactDOM, как видно есть (если я все правильно понимаю)
Однако не распознает HTML теги. Что не так?

```
// Это содержимое app.js
console.log(ReactDOM);
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello</h1>,
    document.getElementById('about-me__body')
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Тот факт, что это не JavaScript

Просто загрузить браузерную версию Babel недостаточно, чтобы браузер внезапно начал поддерживать JSX в обыкновенных тегах с кодом. Необходимо также отметить скрипт соответствующим типом, `text/babel`. И этот момент освещён в [документации по установке (секция <kbd>In the browser</kbd>)](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/).

```
<script type="text/babel" src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

...тогда заработает.

Comment: Спасибо! Я как раз только что нашел этот момент!